# jest mock does not see that it has been called inside if statement in function

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

I am using typescript with typeORM and I have a jest test that looks as followed:

```
    test('add test', async () => {
        testRepoMock = {
            innerTestRepo: ({
                findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null),
                create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ id: 2 }),
            } as unknown) as Repository<ValuesModel>,
        };

        TestService.addvalue(id, testRepoMock);

        expect(testRepoMock.innerTestRepo.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(testRepoMock.innerTestRepo.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

The function I'm testing looks like this:

```
    static async addvalue(
        id: number,
        repos?: { innerTestRepo: Repository<ValuesModel> },
    ): Promise<Values> {
        let repo;
        if (repos) {
            // basically use our mocks if this is a unit test
            repo = repos.innerTestRepo;
        } else {
            repo = await SqlDb.getRepository(ValuesModel);
        }

        let perms = await repo.findOne({ id });

        if (!perms) {
            perms = repo.create();
            perms = {
                ...perms,
            };
            await repo.save(perms);
        }

        return perms;
    }
```

What I cannot figure out is that the `expect(testRepoMock.innerTestRepo.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` keeps reporting that `testRepoMock.innerTestRepo.create` was never called, even though I can log that perms is set to `{id:2}` via the mock and that the if statement is indeed entered.

I even checked what happened if I move the repo.create out of that if statement as a sanity check and then the test passes, so it looks like something about the scope of the if statement confuses jest such that it does not realize that create has been called.

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't have a conditional for testing in your production code. Secondly what *is* orgPermsRepoMock, how does it relate to the testRepoMock you're *actually* passing into addvalue?

Comment: @jonrsharpe orgPerms was a typo, good catch, I fixed that. And the conditional is not in the test, just the function I'm testing, if I understand correctly.

Comment: `findOne` is called asynchronously. thats why you can not check synchronously that consequent `create` was called

Comment: The conditional being in the function you're testing is the problem I refer to. Testing setup shouldn't bleed into production code. I guess you've had the classic issue (this function is hard to test because it creates its own collaborators) and applied the standard solution (so we'll invert the dependency and inject the collaborators to decouple it) but doing so *only* for the test means what you're testing isn't what actually runs in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `await` when you call `addValue`, otherwise your expect lines will be executed before the functions are actually executed

```
test('add test', async () => {
    testRepoMock = {
        innerTestRepo: ({
            findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null),
            create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ id: 2 }),
        } as unknown) as Repository<ValuesModel>,
    };

    await TestService.addvalue(id, testRepoMock);

    expect(testRepoMock.innerTestRepo.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(testRepoMock.innerTestRepo.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: That did it. Dang, maybe I need to go to bed. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is it weird that moving the create out of the if statement would get the test to pass? It passed every time too, so this does not seem like a timing matter. Either way, thanks again.

Comment: if you move it out and put it above `findOne`, yes it will pass, but if put after I don't see how it can pass ....